# How to check for a prime number in Delphi

Tags: delphi, primes

I want to read all prime numbers between 1 and 10000 into a dynamic array and all non-prime numbers into another dynamic array and then read the prime array into `richedit1` so far I have:

```
procedure primearrays;
var
  j, k, l, i, m: integer; // k is the number I am testing for prime number
  // j is used in the for loop to check all numbers smaller than k to see if k is dividable by j
  // l is just a variable set to k mod j to make the if run more smoothly
  // i is the length of the array anotprime
  // m is used to set the length of the array aprime
  bflag: boolean; // bflag is to show if this number is a prime number
  aprime, anotprime: array of integer;
  // aprime is the array of prime and anotprime is the array of nonprime numbers
begin
  j := 0;
  i := 0;
  l := 0;
  richedit1.Lines.Clear;
  bflag := false;
  for k := 2 to 10000 do
  begin
    j := 0;
    while not(j = (k - 1)) do
    begin
      inc(j);
      l := k mod j;
      if (l = 0) then
      begin
        bflag := false;
        inc(i);
        setlength(anotprime, i);
        anotprime[i - 1] := k;
        j := k - 1;
      end
      else
      begin
        bflag := true;
      end;
    end;
    m := -1;
    if (bflag) then
    begin
      inc(m);
      setlength(aprime, m);
      aprime[m - 1] := k;
      richedit1.Lines.Add(inttostr(aprime[l-1]));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

but this doesn't seem to work. It puts all the integers into `anotprime`.

Comment: That isn't the actual code you tried. At the very least, you have typos in there (a variable `aprime` cannot be referred to by typing `apriem`), but the fact that you didn't simply copy and paste the code makes it more likely that there are other errors in there too that aren't wrong in your original version. That aside, what does "this doesn't seem to work" mean? Does it not compile? Does it give wrong results? Does it raise an exception? Have you figured out at which point it's going wrong?

Comment: If only the code had some comments. At least document the *approach* (sieve etc.)

Comment: @hvd I apologize but I programmed it in my home language and had to translate the names I used I accidentally forgot that typo but will fix it immediately. The program runs fine it just puts all the integer values into the array **anotprime** and I debugged it, but it gave me no clue as to where the mistake is.

Comment: is there a specific reason for using arrays and not lists? I have a function that fetches primes which can easily be changed to return a list of primes and non-primes. I can submit it here if you like. Let me know.

Comment: Check for divisors from 2 to n div 2. If you cannot find any it is prime. Use n mod m = 0 to test a divisor. Please format your code to be readable.

Comment: Debugging should involve waiting until you have a known prime number, and seeing what divisor is causing your code to detect it as non-prime. (Since `j` is incremeneted to `1` in the initial inner loop iteration, I think it sees that all numbers are divisible by 1.)

Comment: @DavidHefferman I apologize the comment you just left lost its meaning in translation I believe could you probably repeat it in layman's terms.

Comment: @hvd your last comment fixed my problem for that i am grateful.

Comment: @theunie, the code is now formatted and corrected (did not compile). In the Delphi code editor, mark your source and press ctrl-D to format the code. Paste it into the SO editor, mark it and press ctrl-K.

Comment: in case it interests you, my last foray into primes (which does something similar as your code) is here: https://github.com/stijnsanders/primes

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
procedure TForm1.btnprimeClick(Sender: TObject);
var K, I, iCount : Integer;
begin
  for K := iStart to iEnd do
  begin
    iCount := 0;
    for I := 2 to iEnd do
    begin
      if K mod I = 0 then
      begin
        Inc(iCount);
      end;
    end;
    if iCount = 1 then
    begin
      memData.Lines.Add(IntToStr(K));
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the main problem you have is that you mix all the different aspects (looping over candidates, prime checking, display etc.) into a single function.

Life becomes much easier if you decompose the task into small pieces that just perform a single task. Start with a function to test if a number is prime.

```
function IsPrime(N: Integer): Boolean;
var
  M: Integer;
begin
  Assert(N > 0);
  if N = 1 then // annoying special case
  begin
    Result := False;
    exit;
  end;
  for M := 2 to (N div 2) do
  begin
    if N mod M = 0 then
    begin
      Result := False;
      exit;
    end;
  end;
  Result := True;
end;
```

Now you might wish to make a list containing primes:

```
var 
  Primes: TList<Integer>;
  N: Integer;
....
// create Primes
for N := 1 to 10000 do
  if IsPrime(N) then
    Primes.Add(N);
```

This is not the most efficient way to enumerate primes. But it's probably where you should start and I've mainly written this answer to encourage you to separate code into small logical methods that do specific focused tasks.

Comment: your answer really helped me, thank you and I apologize I keep forgetting that I can write my own procedures, functons etc.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Breaking code down into small re-usable pieces is really important and powerful.

Comment: the 'for m:= 2 to (n div 2) do' loop should be 'for m:= 2 to sqrt (n) do'.

Comment: @No That would do. I preferred to avoid floating point. An integer sqrt would be a nice twist.

Comment: Floating point doesn't play too nicely with **for** loops. How about `Floor(Sqrt(N))` instead?

Comment: @craig That would be just fine

Comment: To make it even faster, it should not check all integers from 2 to sqrt(N), but only the prime numbers in that range.

Comment: @Hans Yes. And then there is http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes